# configuring boost::thread stack size

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there a way to configure the boost::thread stack size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, AFAIK.

Maybe you could try with `native_handle()` thread's member function and set the stack size with a call to OS' API (`pthread_attr_setstacksize()` on POSIX systems maybe?).

Answer (score 2):

Boost evolved and there is a solution: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.attributes

Shorten version

```
boost::thread::attributes attrs;
attrs.set_stack_size(4096*10);
boost::thread deep_thought(attrs, find_the_question, 42);
```

Hope may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, it inherits the process default value for new threads.