# What happens if I don't set a stack size in boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost

[configuring boost::thread stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327384/configuring-boostthread-stack-size)

What happens if I *don't* set the stack size? I am working on a legacy application that sets it to `5* 1024 * 1024` for undocumented reasons. But when I upgraded to C++17 I started getting a seg fault when boost tries to start the thread.

I am not asking for a solution just some guidance on what happens if I don't set the stack size.

Comment: What makes you think the two things are related?

Comment: I am just working through what valgrind is spitting out to find which thing is the seg fault. This is just item #4 I am trying to fix. Also that value is larger than the stack size supported afaik: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program-on-mainstream-oses

Comment: Uh, presumably you get a thread with default (for process or for the entire system) stack size.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen okay that is what I figured but wasn't sure! Thank you!

Comment: Default = 8MB for Linux (in 64 bit builds, anyway), IIRC, and 1MB for Windows.

Comment: _for undocumented reasons_ 